# Change background color for notification entries?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, notifications, customization, samsung-galaxy-5, samsung-touchwiz

Samsung Galaxy 5 (aka 550, Europa, Corby), Samsung's Froyo version (so, Touchwiz.  Launcher is ADW Launcher (non-EX).

My notifications (the things in the list when you pull down the notification bar, if that's the proper terminology I have no idea) are all black on dark gray, and I'd like to change it.  I don't know if it's even possible w/o hackery.

Phone is rooted, upgrade to CM7 or higher is "planned" (for some time now :D).  So, if it's possible to make the notifications more readable there, that would be a solution.

The only readable notification is black on white (or blue on white, not sure), and it's from TaskXP.  So the colors seem not to be hardcoded.

And as always, a RTFM is welcome.  When it includes pointers to *where* in the FM the info is.

Comment: Not sure, but to me this looks like a case for the [UOT kitchen](http://uot.dakra.lt/). They do a lot of GUI mods.

Comment: The issue with this is usually for specific apps. They did not set their "views" correctly for their colors to account for dark backgrounds. If you see it with all notifications then it sounds like an issue with a "theme" you applied (if you did?)